# 405 Error with setChunkedStreamingMode()

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey-2.0

I am trying to download a file from my server. My problem is that if I use `chunkedStreamingMode` the server is return me a `405 - Method not Allowed` Error. If I don't set the `chunkedStreamingMode` the download works perfectly.

I don't understand why the file download with `chunkedStreamingMode` enabled gets rejected by my server. Is there anything I am doing wrong here? Or do I need to set something on the server to get `chunkedStreamingMode` working ?

On my server I have:

```
@GET
@Path("/{fileId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response downloadFile(@PathParam("fileId") long fileId, @Context HttpServletRequest req,
                @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
..
}
```

On the client I use:

```
WebTarget target = rootTarget.path(uri);                            
Invocation.Builder builder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
response = builder.get();
```

I use the following HttpUrlConnectorProvider on my client:

```
private static HttpUrlConnectorProvider buildHttpUrlConnectorProvider(){
     HttpUrlConnectorProvider.ConnectionFactory factory = new HttpUrlConnectorProvider.ConnectionFactory() {
            @Override
            public HttpURLConnection getConnection(URL url) throws IOException {                      
                HttpURLConnection result = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                result.setChunkedStreamingMode(4096);                          
                result.setDoOutput(true);  
                return result;
            }
        };
     return new HttpUrlConnectorProvider().connectionFactory(factory);
}
```

Comment: You could probably diagnose this pretty quickly by running your server in a debugger and stepping through its request handler. You'll find the place where it triggers the 405. Potentially it'll be surrounded by some configuration-driven guard.

Comment: Also, to get any answers, you should tell us what server you're using.

Comment: Also also, I've found that a good rule of thumb is to avoid `HTTPUrlConnection` -- it's full of gotchas. Using Apache HttpClient saves a lot of headaches (but might not necessarily be the problem here).

Comment: @slim thank you for your suggestions I will have a look at them. I am using glassfish btw (I updated the tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by setting the following property for the client config insted of `setChunkedStreamingMode(4096);` in the `HTTPUrlConnection`:

```
.property(ClientProperties.REQUEST_ENTITY_PROCESSING, "CHUNKED");
```